# How to put the print information into a current dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am having brain fart.  I wrote some code to get keywords from my data frame.  It worked, but how can I put the print information into my current data frame.  Thank you for the help in advance.

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
def sort_coo(coo_matrix):
tuples = zip(coo_matrix.col, coo_matrix.data)
return sorted(tuples, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)

def extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names, sorted_items, topn=10):
"""get the feature names and tf-idf score of top n items"""

 #use only topn items from vector
sorted_items = sorted_items[:topn]

score_vals = []
feature_vals = []

# word index and corresponding tf-idf score
for idx, score in sorted_items:

 #keep track of feature name and its corresponding score
    score_vals.append(round(score, 3))
    feature_vals.append(feature_names[idx])

 #create a tuples of feature,score
#results = zip(feature_vals,score_vals)
results= {}
for idx in range(len(feature_vals)):
    results[feature_vals[idx]]=score_vals[idx]
return results

#sort the tf-idf vectors by descending order of scores
sorted_items=sort_coo(tf_idf_vector.tocoo())
#extract only the top n; n here is 10
keywords=extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names,sorted_items,5)

#now print the results -  NEED TO PUT THIS INFORMATION IN MY CURRENT DATAFRAME
print("\nAbstract:")
print(doc)
print("\nKeywords:")
for k in keywords:
   print(k,keywords[k])
```

Comment: `print()` is only to display on screen. In `DataFrame` you puts directly `strings` which you also use in `print()` - `"Abstract:"`, `doc`, `"Keywords:"`. But `DataFrame` was created rather to keep and display table with columns and rows and data to calculations - it is not `Excel` which can mix different objects in different rows, etc.

Comment: Instead of printing, I need to put the information in a dataframe.  I don't want it to print, just store information into a dataframe.

Comment: then create next row and put as other values in DataFrame but you will have to use column name to put in select column. It is not Excel and you can't create nice looking presentation. `DataFrame` was created only to keep data in table format (with rows and columns) and make fast operations on data. But if you want nice looking presentation then maybe generate HTML or PDF.

Comment: Please show an example.

Comment: what example? don't you know how to add row? Pandas: [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: You don't get it.  I did the append and doesn't work with this.  So, you don't understand what I am doing.  It's fine.  I found another way to store my information.

Comment: you didn't say that you already did it. And if it didn't work then you should describe it. We can't read in your mind. So I can not understand what you are doing because you didn't describe all details. and this how Stackoverflow work - if you want help then first you have to describe problem with details. BTW: if you found another way then you could describe it as answer - maybe it will be useful for someone else.

Comment: If you understand the code, you would see append would not work because the length doesn't match.  It's common sense.  That's why I asked  for an example.  Please read the title of this question.  Different lengths are common in NLP.  So I am using different algorithm to fix the issue.

Comment: well this is why I was saing that `DataFrame` is NOT `Excel`. But I have to check `append()` because sometimes DataFrame` may add shorter row and automatically fill empty cell. But frankly I was rather thining of adding empty row with all needed columns and later add expected values. But if you different length (Shorter then current table then it seems obcious that you have add empty columns). Besides You show only single string and you didn't explain that you may have longer elements - and it only show how important is to gives all details in question. We can't read in your mind.

Comment: BTW: if you wnnt example then show example data which we could use in example code. I don't want to create example for random data which may not fit to your problem.

Comment: I checked `append()` on some data - it can add shorter row and fill empty places with `NaN` in this row. And if I add row with new column (which doesn't exists in other rows) then it add `NaN` in other rows.

Comment: It can't be done so I use my go to which is the Jaro Winkler distance for text with record linkage.

Answer (score 0):

First: `DataFrame` is not `Excel` so it may not look like you may expect.

You can use `append()` to add new row with text. It should automatically add `NaN` if row is shorted. OR it will add columns with `NaN` if row is longer.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'X': ['A','B','C'], 
    'Y': ['D','E','F'], 
    'Z': ['G','H','I']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

df = df.append({"X": 'Abstract:'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({"X": 'Keywords:'}, ignore_index=True)

keywords = {"first": 123, "second": 456, "third": 789}

for key, value in keywords.items():
    df = df.append({"X": key, "Y": value}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
# Before

   X  Y  Z
0  A  D  G
1  B  E  H
2  C  F  I

# After

           X    Y    Z
0          A    D    G
1          B    E    H
2          C    F    I
3  Abstract:  NaN  NaN
4  Keywords:  NaN  NaN
5      first  123  NaN
6     second  456  NaN
7      third  789  NaN
```

Eventually later you can replace `NaN` with something else - ie. empty string:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

Result:

```
           X    Y  Z
0          A    D  G
1          B    E  H
2          C    F  I
3  Abstract:        
4  Keywords:        
5      first  123   
6     second  456   
7      third  789
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.  You missed the whole point.

Comment: 1) I have a current dataframe.  2) Extract trigrams by each row 3) the frequency by each trigram in each row.    True, I can create a new dataframe and transpose it. But, the point is not creating a new dataframe but using the current dataframe.  SEE THE KEY IS CURRENT DATAFRAME.

Comment: I went in a different direction and got the job done.

Comment: Again, append doesn't work in this issue.

Comment: then add more information because I have no idea what `issue` you have and why it doesn't work. Better create minimal working code which we could copy and run - to see your real problem. Text `doesn't work` is totally useless for us. And we can't read in your mind.

Comment: BTW: and always put code with correct indentations - current code has wrong indentatiosn and it is useless for us.

Comment: BTW: as for `SEE THE KEY IS CURRENT DATAFRAME` - I can't see beacause I can't run your code. It has wrong indentations and probably it has missing imports or objects - like `tf_idf_vector`

Comment: I know you need to be right.  So you win!  ok.  This project was solved.  You win.  Just leave me alone.  The code works if you know NLP and you are working with Text data.  You win.

Comment: I don't understand you. I try to help you - I show you how to ask good question so we could help you. We don't have to know how to use NLP because many problems can be resolved without this knowledge - but you should show all details and correctly formatted code so we could reproduce problem. And if you don't want help then simply delete question. BTW: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am so sorry, I'm idiot! But, the question is in the realm of NLP.  I will never ask a question again. I did format the code correct, and it works, but the answer you gave me is unusable.  Would you be able to use that dataframe to make graph from that?  Have a great day.